# SQL - How to return a value if nulls is returned

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to write a query for a parameter in SSRS where if it doesn't pull back any data, it will put "None" in the parameter.  Here is what I have tried:

```
    select CASE
    WHEN pt.propertynumber IS NOT NULL
      THEN pt.propertynumber 
    ELSE 'None'
    END AS "Field1"
    from projectmaintenanceproperties pmp
    left join projectmaintenances pm on pm.id = pmp.projectmaintenanceid
    left join properties pt on pt.id = pmp.propertyid
    where pm.id in (:Ops)
    and pt.projectid in ( :Proj )
    order by 1
```

When there is no data pulled back, it is not returning anything in Field1.

How can I tell it to return 'None'?

Comment: Do you just want one record returned with None in case there are no results?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am trying to populate an SSRS parameter, and sometimes it will be Null.  I want it to populate the Parameter with 'None' in that case.

Comment: I have tried coalesce, NVL, and NVL2, with no luck.  The original query works if there is data, but when there is no data, it will NOT return 'None'.  I'm sure it is something stupid I'm missing, but very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, comments are correct - my bad. You'll instead need an IF statement to check if any values are returned:

```
IF EXISTS
(    select CASE
    WHEN pt.propertynumber IS NOT NULL
      THEN pt.propertynumber 
    ELSE 'None'
    END AS "Field1"
    from projectmaintenanceproperties pmp
    left join projectmaintenances pm on pm.id = pmp.projectmaintenanceid
    left join properties pt on pt.id = pmp.propertyid
    where pm.id in (:Ops)
    and pt.projectid in ( :Proj )
    order by 1;
)
THEN select pt.propertynumber [Field1]
    from projectmaintenanceproperties pmp
        left join projectmaintenances pm on pm.id = pmp.projectmaintenanceid
        left join properties pt on pt.id = pmp.propertyid
    where pm.id in (:Ops)
        and pt.projectid in ( :Proj )
    order by 1;
ELSE
    SELECT 'None' AS [Field1];
END IF;
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is looking for.  I think they're looking for a list of parameter values, or if there is no list just return a single record of "none".  If my interpretation is correct, this throws an error when the sub query returns more than one value.

Comment: That is correct.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I am trying to populate a parameter in my SSRS report.  If there is no data from the query, I want it to say 'None' in the parameter.

Comment: Getting an oracle error with that code:

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Likely a PL/SQL vs TSQL thing - I'm not an Oracle guy, but try this edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a bit of a nightmare that might do the trick.  I'm doing this nightmare because I once had a query that very cleverly used UNION and NOT EXISTS to return a completely different query and that resulted in a disastrous query plan when that second query executed.

What I'm doing below is using a fake LEFT OUTER JOIN with a table of only one row to your desired values table.  It's fake because the join predicate is always true.  So for every row from your query that will column from the ForNone query will be returned as well, but ignored since coalesce will return the value from your query (unless it is null, and if that is a possibility you can add a check in your query).  If there are no results from your query then only one row is returned because and coalesce will use the value 'None'.

```
SELECT COALESCE(src.Field1, ForNone.NoneField) AS "Field1"
FROM ( SELECT 'None' AS "NoneField" ) ForNone
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
    select pt.propertynumber AS "Field1"
    from projectmaintenanceproperties pmp
    left join projectmaintenances pm on pm.id = pmp.projectmaintenanceid
    left join properties pt on pt.id = pmp.propertyid
    where pm.id in (:Ops)
    and pt.projectid in ( :Proj )
    order by 1
) src ON 1 = 1
```